# Как он делает такие скриншоты твитера?

Tags: твиттер, скриншоты

Вот [ссылка](http://the-flow.ru/news/twitter-23-07-2018)

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрите на картинках с твиттера текст большой и жирный,  это он с телефона фоткает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого можно добиться например установив в браузере минимальный размер шрифта.

**Вот пример на Safari:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или же какой-то плагин может стоять, которуй увеличивает размер только "контента"

**PS:** На фотографиях из примера многое сделано "ручками". Например в Adobe Photoshop или любом другом графическом редакторе. Обычно так делают, когда переводят твит с одного языка на другой.

Если внимательно посмотреть на верстку твита с большим шрифтом, он отличается по расположению от твита с обычным шрифтом.

Comment: ну очень неплохо с сафари и настройки

Comment: Под виндой плохо будет отображть сафари я думаю , но если короче есть Sleipnir браузер хорошо растеризует анааалисет текст! класс